# Android progressive steaming video with PVMFErrContentInvalidForProgressivePlayback error

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, video-encoding

I am developing app where I have to play progressive steaming video of mp4 file. But I faced the `PVMFErrContentInvalidForProgressivePlayback` error. I think that those videos are not satisfing any of those requirements.

- For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the
  moov atom must precede any mdat
  atoms.
- For 3GPP, MPEG-4, and WebM containers, audio and video samples
  corresponding to the same time offset
  may be no more than 500 KB apart. To
  minimize this audio/video drift,
  consider interleaving audio and video
  in smaller chunk sizes.

But it is not possible to change the file format. Keeping those file are unchanged, how to play those type of mp4 progressive steaming file?

Comment: did you find any solution?